# In C#, why am i getting "can't cast double to float error"?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double

I have the following line of code:

```
    float top = shape.Y + (shape.Height / 2.0) - 4.5;
```

whic is failing with the error' Can't cast double to float.   Shape.Y and shape.height are both type float.

What is causing this error and what is the best was to make sure top is a float (as i need to pass it into another function tha expects a float.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to wrap your numbers with `f`, as normally `2.0` would represent a `double` number. You can read more about `float` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
float top = shape.Y + (shape.Height / 2.0f) - 4.5f;
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause is that your literals `2.0` and `4.5` are of type `double`.

Then in your expression

```
 shape.Y + (shape.Height / 2.0) - 4.5
```

the division seems to be between a `float` and a `double`. But there's an *implicit* conversion from `float` to `double` (the conversion in the other direction is not implicit), so `Height` is "widened" to a `double`. Then to add `Y` to this double, for the same reasons, `Y` too is widened to a `double`. Then the entire expression gets type `double`.

But you declare your `top` variable as a `float`, and the `double` expression cannot be converted to `float` implicitly.

Fuji gave the solution: If you write the literals as `2.0f` (or just `2f`) and `4.5f`, then the addition, division and difference will be calculated as `float`s all the way, and no conversions are needed.

(Actually if you give the denominator as just `2`, it will be converted from `int` to `float` implicitly, but as you can tell by now it is probably easier to see the intention if you include that `f`.)

Comment: I wonder what consideration was given to the floating-point conversion rules?  It seems that implicit double-to-float conversions would be correct 99.9% of the time, while implicit float-to-double conversions are often wrong (e.g. compare the precision of `float f=(float)(1.0/10.0);` to `double d=1.0f/10.0f;`.  Or `float.MaxValue.CompareTo((float)(3.0E+38*2.0))` [correctly reports the float max value as less than 3.0E38*2 as] versus `double.MaxValue.CompareTo(3.0E+38f*2.0f)` [incorrectly reports double max value as less than 3.0E38*2].

Comment: @supercat I understand what you mean. But of course, the reason is that the conversion of _one_ specific `float` to `double` is always exact, and never loses information. The conversion in the other direction, of _one_ specific `double` to `float` generally loses precision, and sometimes projects a finite `double` onto `float.PositiveInfinity` (or negative). So this comes "before" arithmetic (the division and multiplication of your examples).

Comment: If one takes the `double` that most accurately represents some particular numerical value and casts it to `float`, the result will either be the `float` that most accurately represents that value or will be at most a tiny fraction of an LSB worse than the most accurate `float` representation.  If one takes the `float` that most accurately represents a numerical value and assigns it to `double`, the result will seldom be even close to the best representation of the original value.  Losing unnecessary information is far less evil than arbitrarily guessing at necessary information.

Comment: In my first example, I used a division by ten rather than a literal because one might argue that `0.1f` is really source-code representation of the numerical quantity 13421773/134217728 (even though it looks like 1/10).  I would suggest that such a floating point value really means (13421773 +/- 0.5) /134217728.  Even though IEEE requires that the nominal result of floating-point operations must be the correctly-rounded version of the nominal operands, that doesn't mean the values actually *represent* precise quantities.  If they did, ...

Comment: So you're considering `exactMathematicalNumber → float → double` and `exactMathematicalNumber → double → float` where the arrows denote the conversion "mappings". In that case, we can see that the first "composition" starts by throwing away too much precision, and then adds a lot of zero bits to that. While the second composition first throws away some precision, and then throws away some more. So your "logic" makes sense then. But the designers of C# considered only `float → double` (add some zero bits) and `double → float` (throw away precision). So they got their conclusion from that.

Comment: ...then attempting to cast to `float` any `double` whose nominal value does not correspond with the nominal value of any `float` should throw an exception rather than yielding a rounded result (just as casting to `Byte` an `Int32` equal to 258 will throw an exception rather than yielding `2`).  The fact that many different values of `double` can map to one value of `float` without throwing an exception would imply that `double` is the more precise type.

Comment: (Correction: it implies `float` is not the more precise type).  It's worth noting that neither `int` nor `float` is more precise than the other, but the system allows implicit `int` to `float` conversions; consider the computation `float  f=16777217-16777216.0f;`.  No warning, even though the result is numerically just plain wrong.  Changing the second operand of the subtraction from `float` to `double` would yield a correct result, but assigning the result back to `float` would then require an explicit cast.